# Can't set cookie on server side Nuxt.js

Tags: cookies, nuxt.js

I am using initial Nuxt function, that is invoked on reload, to set important data like userId and token. I can read data from cookie, but I can't save data to cookie.

```
initAuth(context, req) {
try {
  const cookie = req.headers.cookie
  if (req && cookie) {
    let token = getCookieServerSide('token', cookie)
    let userId = getCookieServerSide('userId', cookie)
    let deviceId = getCookieServerSide('deviceId', cookie)

    if (token) {
      context.commit('SET_TOKEN', { token })
    }
    if (userId) {
      userId = parseInt(userId)
      context.commit('users/SET_USER_ID', userId, { root: true })
    }
    if (!deviceId) {
      deviceId = generateUniqueId()
      setCookie('deviceId', deviceId)
    }
    context.commit('SET_DEVICE_ID', deviceId)
  }
} catch (error) {}
```

This is initial method, and `setCookie` looks like this:

```
export const setCookie = (name, value) => {
  Cookie.set(name, value)
}
```

By reading different comments this should be valid solution, but cookie isn't saved

Comment: Which library are you using to set your cookies? You will need to use a library that supports setting cookies on the server.

Comment: I recommend this one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-universal-nuxt

Comment: @FlorianPallas I am using `Cookie-js`

Comment: Then try it out using a library that supports server side, like the one @NicolasPennec recommended.

Comment: @NicolasPennec it's working, ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current cookie lib is only compatible with an execution on the front-end code.

To set cookie on both client and server sides, you have to use a lib that supports an **universal** usage, like [`universal-cookie`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/universal-cookie).

With Nuxt, you can use [`cookie-universal-nuxt`](https://npmjs.com/package/cookie-universal-nuxt) to set, get and remove cookies in both client and server side, based on the previous lib.

Comment: The Nuxt auth module doesn't set the cookie also :/

https://auth.nuxtjs.org/